# Adafruit Metro Mini FTDI chip overheating

Tags: adafruit, ftdi

I have an Adafruit Metro Mini board that I am using. After soldering the board and accessories to a perfboard the FTDI chip is overheating, the COM port will not show up on the PC, and the 3V pin does not produce any power while the board is plugged in.

Is there a way to fix this? Have I nuked my board?

Comment: Maybe short or you reversed something

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to fix this?

Yes. Undo whatever short circuit you have created with your soldering.

> Have I nuked my board?

Possibly, possibly not. Most likely the short is making the regulator go into thermal shutdown and no lasting damage has been caused. But you can't be sure.

Answer (score 1):

The 3.3V output of the FTDI chip might be shorted to Gnd, or overloaded by your circuit. Start by checking that.